# How do I refer to a specific HTML <form> or web page from within a .js file?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, cookies

I have a .js file with setCookie() and getCookie() functions which are working fine.  I'm running into a problem when trying to use this same .js file with 2 different web pages.  For example, one page's cookie sets name, room number, and beverage selection, while the other page's cookie sets name, address line 1, address line 2, etc...

Thus, I will need to account for differences in the 2 page's forms in the .js file. I thought that I could reference the particular form I'm addressing by its form name (they have different form names) but that isn't working:

```
    if (document.getElementsByTagName("form") == document.getElementsByName("form1"))
    {  
      document.cookie = 'Name = ' + userName; 'expires = ' + userExpires; 
      document.cookie = 'Room = ' + userPrt1; 'expires = ' + userExpires;
      document.cookie = 'Drink = ' + userPrt2; 'expires = ' + userExpires; 
    }
```

Thus, my question is, when I have to add an if statement to handle code specific to one particular form (or one particular web page), how do I do this?

Thank you

EDIT: I'm not really sure this will be helpful, but since it was requested, here is the HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Javascript</title>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mycss.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="myjs.js"></script>  
</head>
<body onLoad="javascript:getCookie();">
<header>
<img src="js.png" width="800" height="135"/>
</header>
<main>
  <h2>JavaScript Cookie Test</h2> 
  <br><br>
  <form name="form1" id="form1id" action="javascript:setCookie();">
    Name: <input type="text" name="customer" id="customer" required /><br><br>   
    Room: <input type="text" name="roomNumber" id="roomNumber" required /><br><br><br>
    What type of coffee would you like to order?<br><br> <!-- It seems radio input would be better here -->  
    <input type="checkbox" name="cbox" value="regular" />Regular<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="cbox" value="espresso" />Espresso<br> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="cbox" value="cappuccino" />Cappuccino<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="cbox" value="mocha" />Mocha<br>    
    <input type="checkbox" name="cbox" value="raspberry" />Raspberry<br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" /> 
  </form>
</main>
```

As I mentioned, everything works fine in terms of setting and getting the cookie, whether my JavaScript is in the HTML file or in a separate .js file.   It's only when I try to add code in the .js file that references a specific  form (or web page) that I do not succeed.

Should I be referencing the web page instead of the form? If so, how would I do this in an if statement? Thank you!

EDIT: I want to add a brief clarification in case it will be helpful.  What I want to know is how to reference the form or web page calling a function in the .js file.  If form1 or index1.html called the setCookie() function, I want to add an if code block.  If form2 or index2.html called the setCookie() function, I want to add a different if code block.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I finally figured out an answer to this.

HTML:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">var formName = "form1"</script>
  <form name="form1" action="javascript:setCookie(formName);">
  insert form code...   
  </form>
```

Then, in the .js file:

```
  function setCookie(formName)
  {
  insert cookie code...  
  }
```

And the form name is passed to the JavaScript page, so I can use it to add cookie code that is specific to form1.

I was hoping to find a way to know which form called the JavaScript page, but I'm starting to think that's not possible, since the question has been posted for 5 days without a resolution.  Fortunately, this resolves the issue just as easily as knowing which form called the JavaScript page.

I appreciate everyone's input.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried giving each form an id and using getElementById() instead ? I think your error is coming from the fact that getElementsByTagName returns an array so you're trying to compare an array of elements to a single element

Comment: Thank you, I just tried that. Unfortunately, no luck. When I watch it in the inspector, program control just jumps past the document.cookie code as if the if statement were false.

Comment: Could you edit the post to show your html as well? Bit confusing otherwise :)

Comment: I would suggest adding an id to each form you are trying to access, like so `<form id="form1"></form>`. After that, you can select this specific form by using `var form = document.getElementById('form1');`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand your question, but in case I have you could just check if the form exists, by its [id](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id).

```
if (document.getElementById('form1') !== null)
{
    // there is a form1
}
else if (document.getElementById('form2') !== null)
{
    // there is a form2
}
```

Comment: I know that the form exists, I think you misunderstood, but thank you.

Comment: I thought only one of both form exists per page.

Answer (score 0):

for the first, `getElementsByName()` doesn't return single node, but a node collection, so if you want to access the first matching node, you have to use

`document.getElementsByName("form1")[0]`

For the second, you can simply use `document.forms` property where you have access to all forms on your page.

EDIT:

In `document.forms` you can access to form by index of its occurrence (`document.forms[1]` returns the second form on page) or you can use `name` attribute value (`document.forms["form1"]` returns form with name "form1").

Comment: if (document.getElementsByTagName("form") == document.getElementsByName("form1")[0]) did the same thing as my code, it's completely ignored as if it's false.  I'll try your document.forms suggestion in a few minutes, thank you.

Comment: The forms are on separate pages, so if I understand correctly, document.forms["form1"] would not apply.  Instead of trying to access a particular form, is there a way I can access the page (for example, by its relative URL)? Thank you

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName("form")` returns node collection, so try to modify it to `document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0]`. And try to use `isSameNode` for testing results of your DOM queries.

Comment: If they are on separated pages, I think you have no simple option how to access for data from one page to the another.

Comment: If you have generic getCookie() and setCookie() functions in a .js file, there has to be a way to reference the form or web page so that you can add code specific to the particular form or web page.  Every cookie is not equal, they will all have minor differences that have to be accounted for in the cookie code.

Comment: I seem to be having some success with "if (document.getElementsByTagName("form#formid1"))". It's 6:00 am here, bedtime in my case, I will experiment further later today.  Additional  answers are welcomed!